# Laravel scheduler - Run specific days of month at specific time

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to run a task at specific days of month in specific time.
Now i use this code to run the task on 1st and 15th day of the month.

```
$schedule->command('payments:create')->daily()->when(function ()
    {
        $days = [1,15];
        $today = Carbon::today();

        return in_array($today->day, $days);
    });
```

Is there any way to set this task to run on these days at specific time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve it in many ways, following two liner :

```
$schedule->command('payments:create')->monthlyOn(1, '15:00');
$schedule->command('payments:create')->monthlyOn(15, '15:00');
```

if you would like to force a task to run even in maintenance mode, you may use the **evenInMaintenanceMode** method:

```
$schedule->command('payments:create')->monthlyOn(15, '15:00')->evenInMaintenanceMode();
$schedule->command('payments:create')->monthlyOn(1, '15:00')evenInMaintenanceMode();
```

**Another ways (Laravel 5.4 onwards)**  onliner to schedule the event to run twice monthly.

```
$schedule->command('payments:create')->twiceMonthly( 1, 15);
```

If you want to run at specific time then use ->at(); method.

```
$schedule->command('payments:create')->twiceMonthly( 1, 15)->at('13:00');// At 1 PM of every 1st and 15th of every month
```

**Another way** to excute Crontab at midnight of every 1 and 15 of every month

```
 $schedule->command('payments:create')->cron('0 5 1,15 * *');
```

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: How can I do this on laravel 5.1

Comment: monthlyOn can used in higher version only 5.1 doesn't allow to use it

Comment: $schedule->command('payments:create')->cron('0 5 1,15 * *');  this will work in all laravel including one 5.1 as well  : check the "Another way" section  of my answer above

Answer (score 1):

You can use ->mondays() to ->sundays() for specific days every week.

Then use ->at('23:59') for specific time of the day.