# Task Scheduling on custom day Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I want do this job oly on this days can I use at() with when() ????

```
$schedule->command('mycommand')->when(function () {
            $day = Carbon::today()->day;
            if($day == 3 || $day == 5 || $day == 7 || $day == 22) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })->at('17:00');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel scheduler - Run specific days of month at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398476/laravel-scheduler-run-specific-days-of-month-at-specific-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this way :

```php
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(3, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(5, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(7, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(22, '17:00');
```

Or, simpler way, using cron :

```php
$schedule->command('mycommand')->cron('0 17 3,5,7,22 * *');
```

Comment: The cron method is more elegant 

Comment: I guess so, sorry we wrote answers at same time, even if you got few seconds before.

Comment: It's fine for few seconds! not intentional ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate multiple monthly runs on specific days

```php
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(3, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(5, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(7, '17:00');
$schedule->command('mycommand')->monthlyOn(22, '17:00');
```

Hope this helps