# How to subtract days from Laravel command scheduler?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scheduler

I need to run a command that creates database table each year quarter, and I found this command

```
$schedule->command('test:create-table table_test')->quarterly();
```

But I want to run this command a week before, just to be sure that the table already created before I start insert data into it.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel scheduler - Run specific days of month at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398476/laravel-scheduler-run-specific-days-of-month-at-specific-time)

Comment: @miken32 this will allow me to call the cron job each month, but I want to call it once per quarter

Comment: You just add it 4 times on 4 different dates.

Comment: @miken32 That should work, and do you know if define 4 schedulers is expensive than one?

Comment: It's already checking for jobs to run every minute, so nothing makes it more expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly support :D

Comment: Just create an array of dates and loop it, that way you don't have to write 
`->command('test:create-table table_test')->yearlyOn()` a bunch of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, Laravel [implements](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v8.74.0/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ManagesFrequencies.php#L457-L468) "quarterly" as the first day of every quarter at 00:00 with the cron statement `0 0 1 1-12/3 *`

While there isn't a built-in "weekBefore" method, there is a `cron()` method, and you can get fairly close by picking, for example, the 24th day of particular months in a single cron statement. Eg:

```
// Run on the 24th of Mar, Jun, Sept, and Dec
$schedule->command('foo')->cron('0 0 24 3,6,9,12 *');
```

If you wanted to be *exactly* the week before, you'd have to break it up into at least two statements (because Mar & Dec have 31 days, while Jun & Sep have 30).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you: `$schedule->command('test')->yearlyOn(12, 24, 0);`

the first value `12` is the month its the december and the `24` is the day its one before the year is over. The last value ist the time its on `0` a clock!

This is for one week before a year ends. but you need quarterly you can also use `CRON`

Comment: So your point is to create 4 schedules on specific dates? is that right?